# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $a_1^4 + a_2^4 + \cdots + a_n^4 \geqslant n$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, tangent-line-method

> Let $a_1+a_2,...,a_n \in \mathbb{R}.$ Show that if $a_1+a_2+...+a_n=n$, then $$a_1^4+a_2^4+...+a_n^4 \geqslant n.$$

The proposed solution for this was the following:

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice we get

$a_1^4+a_2^4+...+a_n^4 \geqslant \frac{(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)^2}{n} \geqslant \frac{\frac{((a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2)^2}{n}}{n} = \frac{(\frac{n^2}{n})^2}{n} = n$

I can see that we can deduce this straight from the definition, but where on earth does the denominator $n$ come for $a_1^4+a_2^4+...+a_n^4 \geqslant \frac{(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)^2}{n}$.

From Cauchy-Schwarz we can come up with $a_1^4+a_2^4+...+a_n^4 \geqslant (a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)^2$, but I don't see where the denominator comes from. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: This is not true: $\sum a_i^4\ge (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)^2$.  (The reverse is however true: $\sum a_i^4\le (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)^2$.)  If you use C-S you should get $\sum a_i^4\ge \frac1n(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)^2$.

Comment: I would expect a convexity and symmetry argument to imply that the minimum of $\sum a_i^4$ is reached at $(1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Interesting, the solution was proposed on an official page for the national competition.

Comment: But this result is false. Let n=10, $a_i = 0.1$ Then $n=1$ and $\sum_{i=1} ^{10} (0.1)^4= 0.001$ which is less than $n$

Comment: @RyderRude the condition is $\sum a_i=n$, not 1.

Comment: @Bégassat oh thanks for correcting me. So the sum has to be equal to the number of elements. I didn't even notice when assigning two values to $n$ in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator comes from the following:
$$n(a_1^4+...+a_n)^4=(1^2+...+1^2)(a_1^4+_...+a_n^4)\geq(a_1^2+...+a_n^2)^2,$$ which gives
$$a_1^4+...+a_n^4\geq\frac{(a_1^2+...+a_n^2)^2}{n}.$$
Another way: $$\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i^4-1)=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-1)(a_i^3+a_i^2+a_i+1)=$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n((a_i-1)(a_i^3+a_i^2+a_i+1)-4(a_i-1))=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-1)^2(a_i^2+2a_i+3)\geq0.$$

Comment: That's an interesting solution. How did you get the idea to use 3?

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat  It was typo. It should be $4$. I fixed and added something.

Comment: Ok. My question is more about the intuition to add stuff that sums to zero but produces an interesting factorization of the summand with one factor being $>0$. Is this part of a general method? If so, how does one choose the right amount to add (i.e. 4 vs something else)

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat The intuition in the following. $a_i^3+a_i^2+a_i+1=4$ for $a_i=1$, which gives a factor $a_i-1$ again, which gives a factor $(a_i-1)^2$. This method is  named the Tangent Line method.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And I guess then the expectation is that the degree 2 polynomial $P$ with $(a-1)^2\cdot P=(a-1)(a^3+a^2+a+1)-4(a-1)$ to be $\geq 0$ on $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Also we can use Jensen. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, x\mapsto x^4$. Then $f$ is convex and thus by Jensen,

$$\frac{a_1^4+\dots+a_n^4}n=\frac{f(a_1)+\dots+f(a_n)}n\geq f\left(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}n\right)=\frac{(a_1+\dots+a_n)^4}{n^4}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

I always feel that you want to write things very explicitly and lengthily when using Cauchy-Schwarz, or you may forget square roots, or a factor. Here, we use that for any $(b_i)$,
$$
\left | \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \right |= \left | \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \times 1 \right | \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n 1^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2} \sqrt{n},
$$
then take the square, apply to $b_i = a_i^2$, and then to $b_i = a_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $x=(x_{1},...,x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is any vector. We have the following:

Let $u$ be the vector full of ones, in other words $u=(1,1,...,1)$

Then by C-S we have

$$
|\langle x,u\rangle|^{2} \leq  \langle u,u\rangle \cdot \langle x,x\rangle
$$

It's easy to see that $\langle u,u\rangle=n$ and $\langle x,u \rangle=x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n}$. Then:

$$
\left(x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n}\right)^{2} \leq n \langle x,x\rangle = n (x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})
$$

In other words:

$$
\frac{\left(x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n}\right)^{2}}{n} \leq x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2}
$$

When $x_{i}=a_{i}^{2}$ the result follows.

Comment: Note: $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is a bit nicer for inner products (I am using \langle \rangle)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I actually forgot the existence of that, I already change it, thanks.